# Can I just cut this part of the door frame out and replace it?

Tags: wood, doors, frame

I finally hung these doors I found at a second hand store. I am a total amateur so please hold back your giggles. No need to explain how this happened, it was a dumb DIY idea. I just need a fix in terms less technical.  Is there a way to cut this out and just replace the damaged wood?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I hope the pictures explained the question better.

Comment: Do the pictures explain what I'm asking?

Comment: No, not really. A picture only helps so much, but trying to figure out exactly what's wrong is sometimes a futile exercise. Some more explanation will certainly help.

Comment: Thanks. Part of the door frame has been chiseled out. A dumb attempt at fixing a problem. I wanted to hang the doors so they would swing in. I gave up and now I have this eyesore of a frame left.

Comment: Looks like you chiseled out what is called the 'door stop'. To repair, finish the chiseling *completely*, then fill in any low spots with spackle, then buy and install some 1/2 flat pine to serve as the new door stop.  If you want the doors to swing the other way, it is and advanced project. First remove the casing on both sides, remove the jamb assembly intact, reinstall the jamb assembly turn the other way, then re install the casing.

Comment: I like the doors.  Why did you just chisel out part of the door stop?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest thing to do would be to remove the doors and sand it down so that it is all flush and even.  A belt sander would make quick work of this it can be done by hand too if you're willing to put in some sweat.  After sanding it, chisel out material for the hinges, prime, paint and re-hang the door.

It's hard to tell for sure but it looks like the hinges are recessed too far into the door which might be why it didn't close properly.  The hinge should be flush with the edge of the door.  Place a couple washers behind it to bring the hinge out flush with the door.

Comment: You may have confused "easiest" with "most correct" in your answer.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo I thought this was easy but not necessarily correct. Is that what you're trying to say?

Comment: I'm saying I think your answer is a good solution, just not "easy". :)

Comment: My thinking was it's easier to go at something with a belt sander then it is to cut out and replace with correctly sized pieces. Might be time consuming depending how deep you have to go, but not difficult.

Comment: Belt sanders require a certain amount of experience and skill to operate well and safely. So again - not necessarily as easy as one might think.

Comment: He could just buy a pine strip and chisel out the back of it to match any bumps still left.  Might take longer but sounds like a fun puzzle and less messy.